# How to subscribe to a websocket futures channel in GATE IO

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, cryptocurrency

I use this code in python to connect to perpetual futures in Gate IO

```
from websocket import create_connection 
 
ws = create_connection("wss://fx-ws-testnet.gateio.ws/v4/ws/btc") 
ws.send('{"time" : 123456, "channel" : "futures.order_book_update", 
        "event": "subscribe", "payload" : ["BTC_USD", "1000ms", "20"]}') 
print(ws.recv())
```

I also tried adding the `sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}`. Just to see it working, and it didn't help.

It complains that `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]` certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate.

In addition , I tried to connect to the `wss://fx-ws-testnet.gateio.ws/v4/ws/btc` via another `websocket` online platform **https://websocketking.com/**. It also didn't connect for the same reason.

Would appreciate if someone can direct me how can I fix it? Has anyone tried connecting to that `websocket url`?

PS: Example taken from gate io documentation
**https://www.gate.io/docs/developers/futures/ws/en/**

As far as I understood for this channel there is no authentication needed.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct WebSocket URL. In your `create_connection` function, try adding `sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}` to disable SSL certificate verification. Your code would look like this:

   ```python
   import ssl
   from websocket import create_connection

   ws = create_connection("wss://fx-ws-testnet.gateio.ws/v4/ws/btc", sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
   ```

   However, keep in mind that disabling SSL verification is not recommended for production environments as it poses security risks. It's more of a workaround for testing purposes.